# Android - The following classes could not be found: - ListView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Tags: android, xml, listview

when I'm trying to view the Graphical Layout view of my application, I get the following error:

> The following classes could not be found:
>
> - ListView(Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

This is my Activity_main xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="my.com.eltonmkw.parsenoteapp.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Does anyone know what causes this error message to flag? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You probably have something wrong with one of your xml files that isn't allowing the project to compile.

Comment: Hi, @KristyWelsh.
Thanks for feedback, but I found the fix.

     android:id="@android:id/list"

should be stated as..

    android:id="@+id/listview1"

#thankyou #codefix

Comment: thank you again, so glad it's fixed! haha XD
Have a nice day to you @KristyWelsh~ :)